# Literature review of a (possibly) open differential geometry problem

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, soft-question

I recently came across an apparently simple-sounding problem in basic differential geometry, as mentioned below,

**Problem**

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a closed surface of diameter $d$. Suppose that there exists a constant $h < d$ so that whenever a pair of planes separated by a distance of $h$ intersects $S$, the area of $S$ contained between these planes is constant. Does it then follow that $S$ is a sphere?

I searched for references/reviews regarding progress made for this problem, but could not find anything relevant. It would be helpful if someone could point out any relevant material/concepts regarding this problem.

Comment: May I know if there is any context to this question? Is this related to any bigger problem that you are working on?

Comment: @Arctic Char, this is a problem I encountered in an article by professor Mohammed Ghomi. It discussed several such problems some of which were open. If I find the text online I will edit it into the question. However this text didn't have any comment/reference for this problem.

Comment: You could try a reverse search, looking for all articles that cite the article where you found this problem. Depending on where it was published, Mathscinet, ZbMath or something like seminaticscholar might help you.

Answer (score 3):

If you restrict to surfaces of revolution, you should look at Andrew Hwang's paper "A Symplectic Look at Surfaces of Revolution," L'Enseignement Mathématique, **49** (2003), 157-172.